# Scala Swing GUI does not respond to pressed key

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface, reactive-programming

I want to write a Scala interface where I click on an image to draw coloured columns. I would also like to detect if the Enter key is pressed. Here is my tentative code:

```
def main = {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Reactive Swing App"
    val label = new Label {
      var matRaw, mat = new Mat
      mat = Imgcodecs.imread("data/batch/14-ZoneDetection/01-noExtraCol/VISSAGE_115.jp2", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR) // images are stored as 8UC3
      Image.printCaracColor("mat", mat)
      var buf = toBufferedImage(mat)
      icon = new ImageIcon(buf)
      listenTo(mouse.clicks) // mouse.clicks is a member of Label, this is why the click position is relative to the label
      listenTo(keys)
      reactions += {
        case MousePressed(_, point, _, _, _) => {
          mat.submat(0, mat.rows, point.getX.toInt, point.getX.toInt + 1).setTo(new Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0))
          buf = toBufferedImage(mat)
          icon = new ImageIcon(buf)
          println("Click position, x: " + point.getX + ", y: " + point.getY)
        }
      }
      reactions += {
        case KeyPressed(_, Key.Enter, _, _) => {
          println("Enter pressed")
        }
      }
    }
    contents = label
  }

  val frame = top
  frame.resizable = false
  frame.visible = true
}
```

The `case MousePressed` works properly and the a green column is properly added to the displayed image. However, the `case KeyPressed` does not work. Could you help me fix this ?

Comment: Use the image for an `ImageIcon` in a `JButton`. Add an `ActionListener` to the button. It should then respond to both mouse clicks and key presses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if the label is encapsulated in a panel. The label listens to the mouse and the panel to the keyboard.